# What does the chord C(4) mean?

Tags: chord-theory

I am trying to figure out a chord in the song God Is On The Move ([CCLI #7048139](https://songselect.ccli.com/Songs/7048139/god-is-on-the-move)).  What does the chord notation C(4) mean?  This is not a Csus4.

[image: God Is On The Move (excerpt)]

Source: http://www.praisecharts.com/songs/details/27828/god-is-on-the-move-sheet-music/piano-vocal-lead-sheet?key=F

Comment: Couldn't find with that reference. Found 'God is on the move,' with awful chord naming (and key!)

Comment: @Tim I've made an edit with an extract from the actual song, in the referenced key. I suspect we can blame the G♭ major of the original on our friends the guitarists, who like to tune down half a step...

Comment: Tried to download it, failed. The next bar will be crucial, to see where the melody/harmony goes after C(4). I suspect it means C add11 - C,E,G,F. Csus4 with the major third left in.

Comment: @Tim the next line is a repeat of that one, which then transitions to an F5. I didn't want to post too much in case of copyright violation.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of chord notation is common in praise music. If you'll notice the first chord in the excerpt is Bb2 which is the same as Bb(add2).

Dom is correct in that this chord symbol is a C triad with an F. A better way to write this might be C(add4).

If we look at the melody line over this chord we see that it's an A. If we factor that into the chord symbol we get an FMaj7/C. The composer's intent may have been closer to F/C.

I would play:

Bb2 / / / | F / F/C / |

Try these different options out and see what you like the best. Chord symbols can be treated more as a guide. You are the one who ultimately makes the harmonic choices.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely it's a Cadd11 which is just a C major chord with an additional F. If it's not a sus4, the only other option would be C11 which would need to include a minor 7th (B♭). I highly doubt that because it would be extremely odd for the genre to include a chord that dissonant.

Also as a side note: do not use this chord symbol when you want to notate chords. I only leads to confusion like in this case since the symbol is improper.